# Emit the combine observable when any one of the inner one emit

Tags: rxjs

I've two observables `obs1` and `obs2`. I'm looking for an operator that emit when atleast one of them emit. `combineLatest` needs both of them should emit atleast once.

```
import { combineLatest, forkJoin,  of, zip, } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const obs1 = of();
const obs2 = of(1,2,3);

let s = null; 

s = combineLatest(obs1, obs2)
  .pipe(map(([a, b]) => {
    console.log(a, b);
  })).subscribe();
```

Comment: Do you need to be able to tell apart from which observable the value came? Or do you just want one value which is whichever was the last emitted value from either observable?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are searching for `merge`.

```
const obs1$ = timer(1000).pipe(map(() => 'Observable 1 emitted'));
const obs2$ = timer(10000).pipe(map(() => 'Observable 2 emitted'));

merge(obs1$, obs2$).subscribe(console.log);
```

See Stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-kp8od3?file=index.ts